# Find vector that is perpendicular to the line $y=mx+b$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been doing research on how to find a vector that is perpendicular to the a line or a plane. So far, I have been able to find this website:

http://www.rasmus.is/uk/t/F/Su58k05.htm

So accordingly for an equation $y=mx+b$

Finding two points that lie on the line:

Let $x=0$, then $y=b$. Let's call this point $A=(0, b)$
Let $x=1$, then $y=m+b$, let's call this point $B=(1, m+b)$

Then

$
\vec{AB}=\begin{pmatrix}
1-0  \\
m+b-b 
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
m 
\end{pmatrix}$

If I am correct, this vector $\vec{AB}=(1,m)$ is a direction vector that is parallel to the line $y=mx+b$, is that right?

How do I find the normal vector to this line?

Comment: $(-m,1)\perp (1,m)$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner But, how do you find $(-m, 1)$

Comment: Two vectors are othogonal(i.e., perpendicular)  if the dot product is zero.  So you might want to find a vector,  say $(a, b) $ with $(a, b) \cdot (1,m) = 0$

Comment: @Azlif But how do you find it from the equation $y=mx+b$?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, (1,m) is the vector collinear with the line y=mx+b.
(1,-1/m) is one vector perpendicular to the line.
You obtain this vector by solving:
$(1,x)\cdot (1,m)=0$

Answer (score 0):

The line $l_b$ defined by $y=mx+b$ is parallel to line $l_0$ defined by $y=mx+0$, and since vector/point $[1,m]$ is on $l_0$, any 2D vector that's perpendicular to vector $[1,m]$ will be perpendicular to $l_0$, as well as $l_b$.

Now two vectors are perpendicular to each other iff their inner-product is zero. It's not hard to see that $[m,-1]$, $[-m,1]$, $[1,-1/m]$ are all solutions--in fact they are on the same line since they are linearly dependent of each other.